# Is CLSID in registry for windows operating system is constant

Tags: registry

I am developing a windows mobile application where i need to get a registry value of notification settings ,that is stored with  CLSID as a key .Can i depend on the CLSID for retrieving the value of a particular notification event.Will my application works in all the devices if i depend on CLSID .

Answer (score 0):

Most of the system CLSID are constant, to allow dynamic discovery of components; some COM components are using public CLSID.

For example, in DirectShow, filters are retrieved through their CLSID, to enable dynamic building of graphs.

Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) documentation about the CLSID you are interested in to see if it is publicly available and stable.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the CLSID is exactly to tie a particular class to a value that can be queried without executing any code. This is the reason why a CLSID will always work for a particular interface (in your case an event class). In that sense the idea behind IIDs and CLSIDs is the same.

However, it is well possible that the interface is completely unavailable in a subsequent version of the system. Otherwise, the idea behind the CLSID is that the interface is guaranteed to be (binary) compatible.

So either of these applies for the same CLSID value:

1. unavailable
2. compatible